# What is difference between MOSIS and dedicate MPW services of foundries?

Tags: integrated-circuit, prototyping, chip-design

Most foundries, such as TSMC, SMICS, and Samsung have MPW and IC prototyping services.
What is the difference between these services and MOSIS or Europractice?

Question is:
Why use MOSIS services instead of direct use of foundries IC prototyping services?

Comment: They are in different locations?

Comment: Maybe they are cheaper? Maybe they have nicer people working for them? Maybe they provide cakes at meetings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MOSIS is cheaper and has lower minimum order than the other companies mentioned.